# Read tab seperated txt file in pandas (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import

While trying to read a .txt file in pandas, I'm getting an error where the imported file is only one row but has far too many columns.

This is one row from the data

```
    1   182154.6-025557   18:21:54.63   -02:55:57.2  0.0   8.25e-03  1.5e-02       0.20   1.02e-01   -1.95e-01  1.5e-02      55        37      189   0.0   1.53e-01  3.3e-02       0.16   6.32e-01    7.24e-01  6.5e-02      46        29   59   6.2   2.91e-01  5.8e-02       0.17   4.62e-01    6.83e-01  7.0e-02      37        20   54   6.3   3.27e-01  6.2e-02       0.19   3.92e-01    5.51e-01  6.6e-02      37        26   47   0.0   2.28e-01  9.8e-02       0.12  2.50e-01  9.8e-02  46    36       43      7.6        1.1    0.24         0.5     4.6         40    22   36  2     0      starless
```

I'm using the following code to import the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header=None, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')
```

And this outputs:

```
   0                              1      ... 26254                   26255
0      1  182154.6-025557   18:21:54.63  ...   NaN         CO high-V_LSR\n

[1 rows x 26256 columns]
```

Any advice on how to import this data correctly would be very helpful

Comment: The Pandas Import works correctly - you have one row and 26256 columns [1 rows x 26256 columns] - Pandas simply can't output the row in one line and makes line breaks

Comment: why do you use `lineterminator='\r'` ? Maybe lines are separated by `\n` or `\r\n`. And this can be all your problem - it may treat all lines as one row and you get only one row with 26256 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your .txt file isn't quite tab separated.
This code should work for reading in multiple lines from your file. It just splits items if there is whitespace between them.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    raw_data = f.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in raw_data:
        data.append([l for l in line.strip().split(' ') if l !=''])
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I get the following output (dataframe with 63 columns)

```
                0            1            2    3         4        5     6   \
0  182154.6-025557  18:21:54.63  -02:55:57.2  0.0  8.25e-03  1.5e-02  0.20   

         7          8        9   ...   53    54   55   56  57  58  59 60 61  \
0  1.02e-01  -1.95e-01  1.5e-02  ...  1.1  0.24  0.5  4.6  40  22  36  2  0   

         62  
0  starless  

[1 rows x 63 columns]
```

Either that or you want to try…

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header=None, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n')
```